# Выборка в SQL по общей суме нескольких столбцов

Tags: mysql, sql

в общем цель задачи такова, имеем таблицу допустим user в ней имеем некие пять полей, пускай это будет sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5 мне нужно отсортировать по убыванию записи у которых сума (sum1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5) больше. 
То есть цель задачи не сортировка по суме какого то конкретного поля, а по обшей сумме этих пяти полей как будто из всех сложили в единое значение. Пробовал через ORDER BY но не знаю как там задать общую сумму пяти этих полей, знаю только как задать одно конкретное поле, или несколько, но ведь приоритет будет отдаваться первому полю, а мне нужно сортировать по обшей суме 5 полей... 
Спасибо, я просто новичок, не удивляйтесь)
Пример текущего запроса SELECT * FROM user WHERE account = '10' ORDER BY ???? DESC

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE account = '10' ORDER BY (sum1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5) DESC` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого достаточно сложить эти поля в блоке `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
  -- нужные поля для выборки, например все: *,
  sum1+sum2+sum3+sum4 as full_sum
FROM users
ORDER BY full_sum DESC
```

в итоге отсортируется как тебе надо.